# Expo Speech onPause and onResume are not fired when paused or resumed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I set onPause and onResume callback as an option when calling Speech.speak to speak text.
Although pausing and resuming speaking works totally fine, but the callbacks I give to speak function arent fired.
Does anyone know there is a known issue or how to fix it?

SDK Version: ~46.0.9

Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS

`"expo-speech": "~10.3.0"`

I set like this:

```js
const speak = () => {
    Speech.speak(text, {
        ...options,
        onPause: ev => console.log('PAUSED!', ev),
        onResume: ev => console.log('RESUMED! ', ev),
      })
}

// pass the above to button like
<Button title="speak" onPress={speak} />
<Button title="pause" onPress={pauseFunc} />
<Button title="resume" onPress={resumeFunc} />
```

Nothing is logged in console…

Comment: can i get an expo snack,? will check there

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created it here: https://snack.expo.dev/@masafumimori/expo-speech-sample

Comment: @GauravRoy Couldnt figured out why?

Comment: Hey give me some time, will check